# Xcode constraints not changing equally

Tags: ios, uikit, constraints, interface-builder

I'm trying to format a home page of my app and want the distance in the middle of two buttons to stay the same while keeping them centred on the screen using alignment in Xcode. I've been playing around with the constraints forever and can't seem to get it to work. Currently, when on a smaller screen, it seems to favourite the right side editing before the left.

Current alignment settings:

[image: Current alignment settings]

What it looks like on small screen:

[image: What it looks like on small screen]

I’ve been playing around with the alignment setting forever.

Comment: you can use stackview. add these buttons as arranged subviews, setup stackview with appropriate settings, and align stackview itself as you wish

Comment: On a smaller screen there simply may not be enough width to accommodate a 65 point margin either side of the buttons and whatever space you have between them and the width of the buttons. Are you seeing a warning in the console about a constraint being unsatisfiable?

Answer (score -1):

Refer this video

Use stackview and it will make your life easy, i have center aligned the stackview. You can give constrains as per your need.

[image]